# UITableView CustomCell button set JsonParsing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created custom UITableView with a button. User open homepage when click the button.
Homepage Address of the buttons are Json parsing. In other words, the homepage address is different for each button.

I don't know how can I setting a different address for each button.

This is my Source Code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.title setText:[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [cell.date setText:[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]];

    NSString *listSite = [[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"site"];
    UIButton *cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}
```

and this is my SourceCode in `CustomTableCell`

```
(IBAction) selectSite:(id)sender {}
```

Comment: Unclear:  Do you not know how to set the text for a UIButton?  Or do you not know how to process JSON?

Comment: I don't kow how to process JSON :(

Comment: @engine Crate one NSArray and take Address data into that array. Then write this line      cellButton.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[addressArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

Comment: What *do* you know how to do?  Do you know how to use Google?  Have you examined some examples of how to use NSJSONSerialization?  Have you gone to json.org and learned the JSON syntax?

Comment: BTW, the way you'd doing the button won't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your indexpath to UIButton's tag like below

```
cellButton.tag = indexpath.row
```

and use this tag in your UIButton's Action method

```
(IBAction) selectSite:(id)sender {
          int value = [sender tag];
}
```

and set it back to cellForRowAtIndexpath method